# How do I transform a Map<K,V1> to another Map<K,V2> using a map of functions in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to transform a `Map<String, Integer>` to another `Map<String, Long>` using a map of functions in Java 8, matching the data with the functions by key in both maps. You can assume that both maps have the same keys.

I tried the following approach:

```
Map<String, Integer> inputData = new HashMap<>();
inputData.put("A",8);
inputData.put("B",7);
inputData.put("C",6);

Map<String, Function<Integer, Long>> transformers = new HashMap<>();
transformers.put("A", x -> x*2L);
transformers.put("B", x -> x+3L);
transformers.put("C", x -> x+11L);

Map<String, Long> mappedData = inputData.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
         entry.getKey(),
         transformers.get(entry.getKey()).apply(entry.getValue())))
    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

> Expected result: {A=16, B=10, C=17}.

Is there any simpler way of expressing "*apply map of transformers to the map of inputData matching by key*" in Java Streams API?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may transform directly in the collector:

```
Map<String, Long> mappedData = inputData.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
            entry -> transformers.get(entry.getKey()).apply(entry.getValue())));
```

Such solution is shorter and does not create intermediate objects.

Were your `inputData` had the same value type (`Map<String, Long>`), you could perform the transformation in-place:

```
inputData.replaceAll((key, value) -> transformers.get(key).apply(value));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also start from `transformers` map itself, which looks slightly easier:

```
    Map<String, Long> collect = transformers.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                    e -> e.getValue().apply(inputData.get(e.getKey()))));
```

Answer (score 2):

If one extra line does not bother you, try

```
Map<String, Long> result = new HashMap<>(); // this line
inputData.forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k, transformers.get(k).apply(v));
```

Comment: It's generally a Bad Idea (TM) to do this unless you 1) add a massive **not threadsafe** health warning or 2) use a threadsafe collection. Otherwise if someone calls `parallel` on the `Stream` this blows up...

Comment: @BoristheSpider which stream?

Comment: My mistake - I thought you were calling `forEach` on a `Stream` rather than an `Iterable`. My point still stands - the reason for _internal_ iteration (as is the case with `forEach`) is to allow the `Collection` to carry out the iteration as it wishes - potentially in parallel.